# Are Apache Phoenix JARs causing error in Tez?

Tags: hadoop, jar, apache-phoenix, tez

I've tried implementing the Phoenix Storage Handler in Hive according to the documentation [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/hive_storage_handler.html), which as a first step involves including JAR files to the HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH.

I included phoenix-hive.jar and phoenix-client.jar into the path and the table was created successfully. However, unrelated scripts have started failing since this implementation with the following error:

> [ERROR] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: Error starting DAGAppMaster
>   org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.getWebAppContext()Lorg/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext;
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.startServices(DAGAppMaster.java:1737)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.serviceStart(DAGAppMaster.java:1804)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$7.run(DAGAppMaster.java:2379)
>                   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>                   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(DAGAppMaster.java:2375)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.main(DAGAppMaster.java:2179)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.getWebAppContext()Lorg/mortbay/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext;
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:314)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:371)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.web.WebUIService.serviceStart(WebUIService.java:91)
>                   at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$ServiceWithDependency.start(DAGAppMaster.java:1657)
>                   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$ServiceThread.run(DAGAppMaster.java:1678)

Our support team believes these Phoenix JARs are the cause of this issue and has had the JARs removed -- which seems to have resolved the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how these things are related?

Many thanks.